# Plot date on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, weekday

I am trying to plot date (2017/04/24) on the x-axis.  I have volume csv data for a week, Im adding daily volume and plotting them against the day.  I have an array, with the specific day but it doesnt have the month and year.

```
#DETERMINING WEEK DAYS-
weekday_array = []
for i in range (len(timestamp)):
    d = datetime.strptime(timestamp[i], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").day
    weekday_array.append(d)
#print(weekday_array)

#TOTAL DAILY VOLUME
daily_Vol = 0.0
daily_total_vols = []
week_day =[]
weekday_array.append(np.inf)
day = 0

#new_x = dates.datestr2num(date)
for i in range(len(weekday_array)-1):
    start = weekday_array[i]
    next_d = weekday_array[i+1]

    if start== next_d:
        daily_Vol = daily_Vol + volume[i]/10
        day = day+1
    else:
        week_day.append(weekday_array[i])
        daily_Vol = daily_Vol + volume[i]/10
        daily_total_vols.append(daily_Vol)
        daily_Vol = 0.0

weekday_array.remove(np.inf)   #Remove the extra value(infinity) added

#PLOT WEEKLY VOLUME PER DAY
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20.0, 6.0))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_title('WEEKLY VOLUME USDED', fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel('WEEKDAY', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('VOLUME (litres)', fontsize=12)
y = daily_total_vols
x = week_day
ax.bar(x,y,width =0.8,)
for a,b in zip(x,y):
    plt.text(a, b, str(b),fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Basically I would like daily_total_vols on the y-axis and week_day on the x-axis. The x-axis can be 2017/04/24 or Mo,Tu,We,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are after, but if you want weekdays on the x-axis and numbers on the y-axis, you can do:

```
x_days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

plt.xticks(x, x_days)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: plt_result]

Comment: What I have is the day's date, like from 2017-04-25, I use timestamp.day and get 25, so Id have an array of day week_day = [25,26,27,28,29,30,1].   for now my plot just plot the days total volume against the above array.  Id like to get week_day = [Tue,Wed,Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun,Mon] or week_day = [2017-04-25,2017-04-26,2017-04-27,2017-04-28,2017-04-29,2017-04-30,2017-05-01]

Comment: The csv data i get doesnt always start on a monday.